# simple MVC EF query

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I am a MVC EF newb.

I'm trying to do a very simple query. Maybe I'm thinking about it too much in the "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE BLAHBLAH > 3" format and not in a class-based MVC EF layout.

Anyway I have a model/class called "Messages". I'm trying to get all the messages with a specific username. So I have something like this:

```
        var mesg = from msg in elkdb.Messages
                  where mydb.Messages.user = Membership.GetUser()
                  select msg;
```

Visual web developer flags the .msg part of the "where" line and says:

> Error 2
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'msg' and no extension method 'msg'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

msg is defined in the class as follows:

```
public class Message
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    ...
    public string msg { get; set; }
}
```

And I know I have scope access to Message at this point.

Am I laying this out wrong? Do I just have the syntax incorrect?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I mistakenly had "mydb.Messages.msg = Membership.GetUser()" earlier because it was way past my bedtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the query are wrong

```
var mesg = from MSG in elkdb.Messages
                  where MSG.msg == Membership.GetUser()
                  select MSG;
```

does the msg prop match with UserName?

Comment: Ah ... sorry. I meant to put "mydb.Messages.user = Membership.GetUser()". So I guess "MSG" is just a temporary tuple for this query?